# Help in evaluating $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k}\sin (\frac{a}{k})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

I would like to try to evaluate

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin (\frac{a}{k})}{k}$$

However, all of my attempts have been fruitless.  Even Wolfram Alpha cannot evaluate this sum.  Can someone help me evaluate this interesting sum?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the [Hardy-Littlewood function](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/plms/s2-41.4.257) (see [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jat.2004.02.008) and [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s1-25.1.5) as well), which is known to be very slowly convergent. Walter Gautschi, in [this article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2004.09.043), shows that

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k}\sin\frac{x}{k}=\int_0^\infty \frac{\operatorname{bei}(2\sqrt{xu})}{\exp\,u-1}\mathrm du$$

where $\operatorname{bei}(x)=\operatorname{bei}_0(x)$ is a [Kelvin function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.61.E1), through Laplace transform techniques (i.e., $\mathcal{L} \{\operatorname{bei}(2\sqrt{xt})\}=\sin(x/s)/s$), and gives a few methods for efficiently evaluating the integral.

---

Here's a plot of the Hardy-Littlewood function:

[image: plot of Hardy-Littlewood function]